# What is the deeper connection of vedic rituals to sunrise?

Tags: vedic-rituals

What is the deeper significance of the tradition of vedic rituals being indispensable for the sun to rise in the morning (consequently the world to continue to exist)? 
My feeling is that man cannot be absent when such a mighty event occurs, but why in this precise manner?
But evidently the sun will rise whether man is present or not, so it must be something more than the physical sun involved. 
So I'm asking for clues to this mystic side, if possible something more substantial than "poetic symbols that produce nice feelings" that I have been able to think of, or read about, so far.